# How can I find answered questions?

Tags: support, search

We have a tab to see all unanswered questions.  Is there a way to query all answered questions for a particular tag?  I would like this for reading and learning purposes.

Reading answered questions provides a lot of knowledge as it starts from a problem, has all the possible solutions and a best solution as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to find answered questions.

For example, to find questions with at least one answer with the tag [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), search for:

```
[c#] answers:1
```

To find questions with an accepted answer, search for:

```
[c#] hasaccepted:yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to click on a tag.  It will give you the highest-voted questions in that tag, in descending order.  Most of these are already answered.

If you want to filter out the questions without answers, do a search for the tag, and add `answers:1` to it, like this:

```
[c#] answers:1
```

If you don't get the Votes tab by default, just click on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the search page and use `answers:1+ [TagGoesHere]` to get answered questions for a tag.